# ReactTS: Align items in a Stack MUI

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if I can have 2 controls in a horizontal-oriented Stack so that the left item should be docked to the left side of the Stack, and two typography items should be positioned in the middle of the row.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Typography, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import Box, { BoxProps } from "@mui/material/Box";

function Item(props: BoxProps) {
  const { sx, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        ...sx,
      }}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

export default function DirectionStack() {
  return (
    <Item>
        <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="left">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="small"
            sx={{ backgroundColor: "#1B1C89", marginTop: '15px' }}
          >
            My button
          </Button>
        </Stack>
        <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="center">
          <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Some Text</Typography>
          <Typography sx={{ color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Some Green Text</Typography>
        </Stack>
      </Item>
  );
}
```

In the snippet above I want the Button to be docked to the left side of the text inside the two Typography items should be positioned in the middle, in each row.

What I am trying to achieve looks something like this:
[image]

Now looks like this:
[image: How it looks now]

Comment: Can you provide an example image of what is the actual produced output?

Comment: provided, you can easily run in a codesandbox instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but I landed here and had a similar question that I solved like this

```
  <Stack
    direction="row"
    justifyContent="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
    sx={{ p: 1, mt: 2, backgroundColor: "#ccc" }}
  >
    <Button variant="contained">My button</Button>
    <Stack>
      <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "1.2em" }}>
        Some text
      </Typography>
      <Typography color="green">Some green text</Typography>
    </Stack>
    <span id="dummy"></span>
  </Stack>
```

[image: Edit mui-stack-example]